# $(element).data("dataAtribute") vs $(element).hasClass("className")

Tags: javascript, jquery

Which is quicker in jQuery?

```
$(element).data("dataAtribute");
```

or

```
$(element).hasClass("className");
```

Comment: OK. Point taken.  The reason I ask is because I want to do 'something' depending on whether a HTML element has a particular attribute.  I just wondered (and being lazy) whether adding this check via a class name or a data attribute would make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guess was [`.hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) since it doesn't have to work with custom attributes, but checks the native `.className` attribute.

According to [this test](http://jsperf.com/data-vs-hasclass) I am right. But didn't think it would be THAT much (~90%) of a difference though.

Checking these methods in the source (see [src/data.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js) and [src/attributes.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js)) makes it quite clear.

Comment: wow - that is a surprise!  Many thanks for taking the time out to run the test - I had every intention of doing something, after the earlier @Dunhamzzz 's answer, but you beat me to it - and with a much better demo than I would have produced.  Hopefully, you've proved that it was not such a dumb question afetr all.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Sniffer you're welcome! There are no dumb questions, only dumb people :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try it and see** - especially as this is so simple. Please report back with your findings too.

I would guess that `data()` is quicker as it's directly checking an attribute, as opposed to having to search the class attribute for a value.

Comment: Again, point taken.  I just wondered if someone had already carried out the tests to save me time. I didn't realise this question would cause such mirth!